# Is it possible to create swift classes and objective-C classes in the same pod?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, header-files

I am using Cocoapods. I'm creating a Pod.

Most of the classes are written in `Swift`.
I would like to write a class in `Objective-C` using one of the `Swift` class.

I don't know how to import the "corresponding header". In a usual project, I would have used the "NameProject-Swift.h" file, but within a Pod, I don't know how to do.

How can I do?

Comment: It should be possible to have a Swift wrapper for ObjC classes, yes.

Comment: The project within the Pod should define a module (this will be the default).  Use the module's name in the `<module>-Swift.h` import.

Comment: The name of my Pod is `MyPod` and I don't specify any module name for my pod. When I try to `#import "MyPod-Swift.h"`, I have the following error: 
`"MyPod-Swift.h" file not found`. Do I need to do something else to enable the bridging?

Comment: Even with specifying a `module_name` it does not work.